# select total of field for the last 7 days and group by date and values

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I am sure this is pretty simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly here. I am trying to get totals for certain fields over the last 7 days and group them by date and field. 
Example:

The following table:

```
TABLE API_LOG
  COLUMNS 
      customer
      ip_address
      date_logged
      endpoint
```

So I would like to get the total endpoint calls for the last 7 days per customer and ip_address. I already have the daily totals organized but for some reason cannot get this to group correctly.

```
SELECT  date_logged AS DATE_LOG, Customer,
    COUNT(customer) AS CustomerCount, COUNT(ip_address) as IPCOUNT
   FROM API_log
GROUP BY date_logged, Customer
```

The idea is then to bind this to a chart.
Sample data:

[image]

Expected output;

[image]

Current Output:

[image]

Appreciate assistance with this.

edit:

I group by date because I want to see the total for each day for the last 7 days. In other words, give me the total counts for each customer by day.

Comment: you will need to add some sample data and based on that show expected output

Comment: What do you group by date when you say you need per ip address?

Comment: You are showing some different things. With your query you can not get what you are showing to us on the last pic. If `date_log` column contain time part then sure you will get that and in this case you should group by `cast(date_lod as date)` instead

Comment: My query was basically returning all records per day as individual rows. The mistake was that I was not casting the datetime as date. Thanks for your responses though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your date_logged column is datetime so it makes sense that you are getting separate dates when grouping. Try this

```
SELECT  CAST(date_logged AS DATE) AS DATE_LOG, Customer,
    COUNT(customer) AS CustomerCount, COUNT(ip_address) as IPCOUNT
   FROM API_log
GROUP BY CAST(date_logged AS DATE), Customer
```

Comment: you are awesome. Thanks. Really Appreciate it.

Comment: sorry one more thing, to ensure only last 7 days, I assume I can just put where date_logged between current date and getdate() -7 or WHERE date_logged > getdate() - 7?

Comment: @vbnewbie Since we are assuming your date_logged is a datetime field you have to be specific about the 7 days. For instance for simple math lets say it was one day. 1/1/2016 7PM -  1/2/2016 7PM? Or just anything between 1/1/2016 12AM and 1/2/2016 12AM?

Comment: Yes I understand although the following worked fine given that date_logged is a datetime field...WHERE date_logged > getdate() - 7. But to answer your question, yes it would be anything between 1/1/2016 12AM and 1/2/2016 12AM